# ASP.NET Core Application registers following url https://gearssdk.opswat.com/ even though I was not registered it

Tags: asp.net-core

I have noticed that my app is receiving requests to https://gearssdk.opswat.com/ even though I never registered this url

I'm building asp.net core web app with asp.net.core 3.1 framework

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmP5Z.png)

edit:
this happens both on my PC during debugging and on staging instances
this url is not resolving when app is not running.

Comment: if your app is online on server, so it will be probably bot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like your app might be intercepting traffic intended for some security tool that's installed on your machine.

If you run `nslookup gearssdk.opswat.com` from your machine, you should get a response of 127.0.0.1, which is the local loopback address. You could try listening on a different port

Comment: You are probably right, I've removed port  443  ["https://+:443"] from my UseUrls() and app is not receiving calls to this endpoint